# How can I do a force restart?

Tags: pi-3, kodi, reboot

I'm wondering once I'm in Kodi and it freezes what do I do? Is it possible to force quit the program? or is there a way to do a reboot of the system? It's happened a few times now where the system freezes and I seem to always have to pull the power to reboot. I'm wondering if there are better steps to do before It comes to that. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1-6</kbd>.  At least one of this should take you to a plain text login.  From there you should be able to get the PID of the Kodi process -- presuming it's called `kodi`, which I don't know:

```
ps -C kodi
```

This will respond with a number, or nothing it it is not actually called `kodi`, in which case you could try `ps -A | grep kodi` to see if it is something more elaborate (e.g `kodi-foo`). Once you have the PID number:

```
sudo kill ...
```

Where `...` is the number.  If that doesn't work, try `kill -9 ...`.

If/once you are sure of the name of the process you can also just use:

```
sudo killall kodi
```

To save looking up the PID. You can use `-9` with `killall`.